# Different positions of caret in the pattern of grep command?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I am a newbie to Linux. Recently I learned how to use grep command and how to search a text at the beginning of each line. But there seems to be two patterns to fulfill this.

For example, if I want to search all lines start with "W", I can execute:

```
grep "^W" filename
```

Most articles suggest using this way. But I also encountered another pattern:

```
grep ^"W" filename
```

And it also works.

So what is the difference between these two? Are they equivalent to each other? And how can the caret be put outside the quotes (I mean in most languages the pattern should be a string and the caret should definitely be put inside the quotes)?

Answer (score 3):

This works because Bash evaluates contents of each pair of quotes before running the command (possibly expanding variables, if there are any), and removes them afterwards. You can even write `grep ""^"ab"c"""" filename`, and it will also work, as for Bash the value ends up being simply `^abc`.

Comment: Not just bash: (probably) any shell that is [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) compatible will do this. It's called [quote removal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_07).

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that you don't need to quote your regular expressions. For example, you can do

```
grep W filename
```

You could also do

```
grep ^W filename
```

Bash will take any quoted string, and return its "string value" before executing the command. So `^"W"` is passed to the grep command as `^W`, and it is none the wiser that there were quotes originally.

So

```
grep ^W filename
```

and

```
grep ^"W" filename
```

are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep commands for regex without quotes too.. but it takes some processing for the shell to expand and analyse it (for argument part and switches) before delegating it to the search tool (grep).

So, it is considered good practice to give arguments within quotes.

**Ex:** `grep hello file` requires additional effort to identify `hello` as an argument where as `grep "hello" file` doesn't.

Where to find **difference:**

`grep "-i hello" file` and `grep -i hello file` and `grep -i "hello" file` in the latter case.. `i` is the switch for ignore case and `"hello"` is argument.

Read more [here](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html)

HTH

Comment: I think you mean `-i`, currently this would look for `i` in files `hello` and `file`